# All Characters Around Keyword but Stop at Spaces

Tags: regex, string, atom-editor

[image]

**OPSDTLHDR 1000ACTIVE  MATCHSOMETHINGSOMETHING**

**INPTSTHDR AKKCCT_APSMATCHSOMETHING**

In the above image, the keyword is "MATCH". I want everything around MATCH, but I need to stop at spaces.

From the first line, I would need MATCHSOMETHINGSOMETHING and from the second AKKCCT_APMATCHSOMETHING.

If  `(MATCH)\w+`, MATCHSOMETHINGSOMETHING comes through ok, but only get MATCHSOMETHING from the second line.

If  `.+?(MATCH)\w+`, I get back the both entire lines.

If `\w+?(MATCH)\w+`, I get back AKKCCT_APMATCHSOMETHING but nothing from the first.

I'm working in Atom Text Editor.

Comment: Don't display images with text, we can't copy/paste them to test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern `(MATCH)\w+` will capture `MATCH` in a capturing group followed by one or more times a word character which will match `MATCHSOMETHING` in `AKKCCT_APMATCHSOMETHING`

Using `.+?(MATCH)\w+` will match both lines because you use the dot which also matches a whitespace so that will match up till `OPSDTLHDR 1000ACTIVE MATCH` and then matches the rest of the word characters.

`\w+?(MATCH)\w+` does not match the first because the `\w+` matches at least one word character before `MATCH`

You could match not a whitespace character `\S` zero or more times,  followed by `MATCH` and then again not a whitespace character zero or more times:

`\S*MATCH\S*`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mMqsQH/1)